# Passing Data EventSource Server Sent Event (SSE) as another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page that update latitude,longitude from database every X seconds and display the values. I'm using Server-Sent Event to update the value. My Server-Sent Event not have any problem. It can update latitude,longitude and speed on page every X seconds. My problem is I want to pass the latitude, longitude value to google map script to add a marker. How can I do it?

Example this script will retrieve latitude value from database.

```
latitude.onmessage = function(e) {
    //document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML += e.data + '<br />';
    ('#latitude').text(e.data);
};
```

How can I pass the latitude value to this code.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(LATITUDE VALUE, LONGITUDE VALUE),
    map: map
});
```

Below is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Example server sent event</p><br>
    Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span><br>
    Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span><br>
    Speed: <span id="speed"></span>

    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:380px;"></div><script>

                    function initialize()
                    {
                        var latitude = new EventSource("<?php echo base_url() . 'sse_push/getLatitude'; ?>");
                        var lgt;
                        var lat;
                        latitude.onmessage = function (e) {
                            //document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML += e.data + '<br />';
                            $('#latitude').text(e.data);
                        };
                        var longitude = new EventSource("<?php echo base_url() . 'sse_push/getLongitude'; ?>");
                        longitude.onmessage = function (e) {
                            //document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML += e.data + '<br />';
                            $('#longitude').text(e.data);
                        };
                        var speed = new EventSource("<?php echo base_url() . 'sse_push/getSpeed'; ?>");
                        speed.onmessage = function (e) {
                            //document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML += e.data + '<br />';
                            $('#speed').text(e.data);
                        };

                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                            zoom: 10,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        });

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lgt),
                                map: map
                            });

                        marker.setMap(map);
                    }
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
latitude.onmessage = function(e) {
    //document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML += e.data + '<br />';
    ('#latitude').text(e.data);
    sessionStorage.setItem("latitude",e.data);
}; 

longitude.onmessage = function(e) {
    //document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML += e.data + '<br />';
    ('#latitude').text(e.data);
    sessionStorage.setItem("longitude",e.data);
}; 

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(sessionStorage.latitude, sessionStorage. longitude),
    map: map
});
```